# How to get all the VM's information for all Projects in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform-provider-gcp

How to get all the VM's information for all Projects in GCP.

I have multiple Projects in My GCP account and I need the Operating System, Version of Operating of System and Build Version of the Operating System for All the VM's for all Project in GCP.

Comment: Do you have access to the organization of these projects !?

Comment: yes I have access

Comment: Maybe you can get the information that you need using Google Cloud Security Center (https://cloud.google.com/security-command-center/docs/). Let me know if it helps you.

Comment: This is not information that GCP / GCP tools provide. You will either need to create your own tooling or use third party software. I have not seen anything for this task. If anyone knows of a tool please add to the comments.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't find a tool to that, so I code something that you can use. 
This code must be improved, but here you can find a way to scan all project and get information about the OS.

Let me know if it helps you.

**Pip install:**

```
!pip install google-cloud
!pip install google-api-python-client
!pip install oauth2client
```

**Code:**

```
import subprocess
import sys
import logging
import threading
import pprint

logger = logging.Logger('catch_all')

def execute_bash(parameters):
    try:
        return subprocess.check_output(parameters)
    except Exception as e: 
       logger.error(e) 
       logger.error('ERROR: Looking in jupyter console for more information')

def scan_gce(project, results_scan):
    print('Scanning project: "{}"'.format(project))
    ex = execute_bash(['gcloud','compute', 'instances', 'list', '--project', project, '--format=value(name,zone, status)'])
    list_result_vms = []
    if ex:
        list_vms = ex.decode("utf-8").split('\n')
        for vm in list_vms:
            if vm:
                vm_info = vm.split('\t')
                print('Scanning Instance: "{}" in project "{}"'.format(vm_info[0], project))
                results_bytes = execute_bash(['gcloud', 'compute', '--project',project, 
                                        'ssh', '--zone', vm_info[1],  vm_info[0], 
                                        '--command', 'cat /etc/*-release'  ])
                if results_bytes:
                    results = results_bytes.decode("utf-8").split('\n')
                    list_result_vms.append({'instance_name': vm_info[0],'result':results})


    results_scan.append({'project':project, 'vms':list_result_vms})


list_projects = execute_bash(['gcloud','projects', 'list', '--format=value(projectId)']).decode("utf-8").split('\n')
threads_project = []
results_scan = []
for project in list_projects :
    t = threading.Thread(target=scan_gce, args=(project, results_scan))
    threads_project.append(t)
    t.start()

for t in threads_project:
    t.join()

for result in results_scan:
    pprint.pprint(result)
```

You can find the full code [here](https://github.com/kanjih-ciandt/jupyter-gcp/blob/master/GCE-VM-Information.ipynb):

Comment: Just an FYI for future readers, google has its own GCP python client library that is rather robust. Instead of using bash or subprocess commands in python it will be much faster (and more comparable with products such as cloud functions and lambda) to use the aggrigated.list python API. located here https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/aggregatedList

Comment: google api command does it for one project only. How can you search all projects and folders for a VM name?

Comment: "execute_bash(['gcloud','projects', 'list', '--format=value(projectId)']).decode("utf-8").split('\n')" returns  a list with all project that you have access

Answer (score 1):

Wuick and dirty:

```
gcloud projects list --format 'value(PROJECT_ID)' >> proj_list

cat proj_list | while read pj; do gcloud compute instances list --project $pj; done
```

Comment: From Review: Please add some explanation to your solution.

Comment: This works if Compute Engine API has been enabled in all your projects - otherwise it will error out as written. Additionally you will see both running and terminated VMs.

Add `--quiet` to get around the error issue:
`cat proj_list | while read pj; do gcloud compute instances list --project $pj --quiet; done`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command in the Cloud Shell to fetch all projects and then show the instances for each of them:

```
for i in $(gcloud projects list |  sed 1d | cut -f1 -d$' '); do 
gcloud compute instances list --project $i;done;
```

note: make sure you have compute.instances.list permission to all of the projects

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you do it using the `pip3 install -U google-api-python-client` without using bash. Note, this is to be ran with keyless auth. Using service account keys is bad practice.

https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/main/docs/start.md
https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/main/docs/dyn/index.md
https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/compute_v1.html

```py
from googleapiclient import discovery
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
import yaml
import structlog

logger = structlog.stdlib.get_logger()

def get_projects() -> list:
    projects: list = []
    service = discovery.build('cloudresourcemanager','v1', cache_discovery=False)

    request = service.projects().list()
    response = request.execute()

    for project in response.get('projects'):
            projects.append(project.get("projectId"))

    logger.debug('got projects', projects=projects)
    return projects

def get_zones(project: str) -> list:
    zones: list = []
    service = discovery.build('compute','v1', cache_discovery=False)

    request = service.zones().list(project=project)

    while request is not None:
        response = request.execute()
        if not 'items' in response:
            logger.warn('no zones found')
            return {}

        for zone in response.get('items'):
            zones.append(zone.get('name'))

        request = service.zones().list_next(previous_request=request,previous_response=response)

    logger.debug('got zones', zones=zones)
    return zones

def get_vms() -> list:
    vms: list = []
    projects: list = get_projects()
    service = discovery.build('compute', 'v1', cache_discovery=False)

    for project in projects:
        try:
            zones: list = get_zones(project)

            for zone in zones:
                request = service.instances().list(project=project, zone=zone)
                response = request.execute()

                if 'items' in response:
                    for vm in response.get('items'):
                        ips: list = []

                        for interface in vm.get('networkInterfaces'):
                            ips.append(interface.get('networkIP'))

                        vms.append({vm.get('name'): {'self_link': vm.get('selfLink'), 'ips': ips}})

        except HttpError:
            pass

    logger.debug('got vms', vms=vms)
    return vms

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = get_vms()

    with open('output.yaml', 'w') as fh:
        yaml.dump(data, fh)
```