# List resources in GCP Shared VPC

Tags: google-cloud-platform, shared, google-vpc

I am looking for API that can list VMs or other resources in GCP Shared VPC

Eg:
Host Project: Project1,
Service Project: Project 2,
Shared VPC: VPC1,
VPC1 has two instances VM1 in Project1 and VM2 in Project2

I would am looking for API that can list both VM1 and VM2 while I am in host project.

compute.instance.list is only listing the VMs in Project1 only.

Thanks,
Ranjish

Answer (score 0):

Resources in Google Cloud are organized into a hierarchy, with each node (Organizations, Folders, Projects, and so forth) having a reference to its parent. You can use that reference as a key filter term for scans to improve the consistency of resource searches.

You can grant users permissions using custom roles. These roles operate on the principle of least privilege, and generally provide only the minimum necessary permissions required to do a particular task.

Here is some useful information about [listing](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/listing-all-resources) your resources.

Also here is a [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54770980/how-to-get-all-the-vms-information-for-all-projects-in-gcp) thread that talks about this request.

You can also check this [metrics for multiple projects](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/settings/multiple-projects) in GCP.

Comment: Thanks for your response Vicente. I understand this is the way that we need to follow when we are dealing with multiple projects. But is this the case with shared VPC as well, as host project will have access to those resources in the other project, being in Shared VPC?

Comment: Organizations, folders, and projects

Shared VPC connects projects within the same organization. Linked projects can be in the same or different folders, but if they are in different folders the admin must have Shared VPC Admin rights to both folders. Refer to the Google Cloud resource hierarchy for more information about organizations, folders, and projects.
Take a look to this resource, it might help you.
https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/shared-vpc#resources_that_can_be_attached_to_shared_vpc_networks_from_a_service_project